# Boolean and string condition

Tags: php

I have to change my status to words in a method but when I pass argument as a string to the method, I get result from both of the conditions:

```
public static function Status($status)
{
    if ($status == true || $status == True  || $status == 'true' || $status == 'True' || $status == 1)
    {
        echo "true";
    }
   if ($status == false || $status == False || $status == 'false' || $status == 'False' || $status == 0)
    {
        echo "false";
    }
}
```

When I pass 'False' value as string to the method I get `truefalse` result but I don't have any problems with string values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `===` instead of `==` to check if the value is identical. Because any string will be considered as `true` if compared without checking variable type. So, change your code to

```
function Status($status)
{
    if ($status === true || $status === True  || $status === 'true' || $status === 'True' || $status === 1)
    {
        echo "true";
    }
    if ($status === false || $status === False || $status === 'false' || $status === 'False' || $status === 0)
    {
        echo "false";
    }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Test it ,,, I do that ,, but I got  same result `truefalse`

Comment: @Pedrammarandi I've updated my answer. I tested it, and it works fine.

Comment: thank you works fine,, but why have to do that ,, sometimes we pass only pass string value of false but we use `===`

Comment: @Pedrammarandi because any string will be considered as `true` if compared without checking variable type.

Answer (score 1):

A simple trick that might come in handy:

```
if (is_string($status)) $status = json_decode($status);
if ($status) {
   echo "true";
}
else {
   echo "false";
}
```

json_decode will convert 'False' or 'false' into a boolean **false**, same with true.

Another way of doing this would be to leave strings alone, so convert booleans and integers to the string 'true' and 'false'.

```
if (!is_string($status)) $status = ($status) ? "true" : "false";
echo $status;
```